# Difficulty running a Python code in Visual Studio Code, runs in the Python shell but not here

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I have been coding in Python in Visual Studio Code. I have started with Tkinter. I was running the following code (see attached picture) and it did not work, however it did in the Python shell. Details are all in the picture, as to what the error is
Image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx0b6.png

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()

topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button1 = Button(topFrame, text="button 1", fg="red")
button2 = Button(topFrame, text="button 2", fg="orange")
button3 = Button(topFrame, text="buton 3", fg="yellow")
button4 = Button(topFrame, text="button 4", fg="green")

button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
button4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you only have one copy of python installed? If you're using windows how did you install python?

Comment: I installed python regularly - from the Microsoft store. The Python extension for visual studio, i installed from within the application.

Answer (score 2):

The python import priority:

- current directory
- current user directory
- global directory

Based on the provided screenshot, the script file have the same name as the module you are trying to use: `tkinter` (see point N1 from the priority). Additionally, the import were done using "*", no verification is done on the import time, whatever module have `Tk` object/class or not

**To avoid the issue**: rename your file to something else.

Best practices:

- Do not import via glob aka "*", instead use strict import
- do not name files the same as the existing standard libs

Answer (score 0):

If C:\Users...\Desktop\tkinter.py is your hand-made script file.
Try to rename C:\Users...\Desktop\tkinter.py to another. For example my_tkinter.py.
Probably Python use tkinter.py module file in same directory with visualStudioCode.py which are not default library module.